# Validate multiple fields and showing a message

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a pretty simple form. I want to show the message "Please say something! I want to hear from you!" on my website when people leave the fields empty. How to go about it ?

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
  <label for="comment">Comment</label>
  <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Did either of the answers help you solve your question? If so, please mark one as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. You listen for the submit from the button and when that happens you stop the form from submitting with `event.preventDefault()`, so you can check the values. We set up the form fields in an array called `check`, so we can loop through them and check for their value. If the value is empty, we make a note of that in a `error` array. At the end, we check to see if there are errors and if so, display the alert. If not, allow the form to submit.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting
  let form = document.querySelector('form');
  let check = ['name', 'email', 'comment'];
  let error = [];
  check.forEach(field => {
    if (form.querySelector('#' + field).value.trim() === '') {
      error.push(field);
    }
  })

  if (error.length > 0) {
    alert('Please say something! I want to hear from you! The following fields are missing information: ' + error.join(", "));
  } else {
    form.submit();
  }


})
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
  <label for="comment">Comment</label>
  <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `required` attribute to your inputs and the `novalidate` attribute to the form (so we can use our own validation). Then, use `form.checkValidity()` to check whether all fields have been filled in.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  if (!this.checkValidity()) {
    document.querySelector('#error').style.display = 'block';
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```css
#error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" novalidate>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>
  <label for="comment">Comment</label>
  <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" required><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<p id="error">Please say something! I want to hear from you!</p>
```